# Login in Spring security special character in password

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I am new to spring security.The default login url of oauth is like:

```
{{base url}}/oauth/token?username=your_username&password=ourpassword&grant_type=password&client_id=customer-client
```

This works fine but, when my password has special characters like # * in the password it does not work.
Any solutions?

Comment: Did use use the URL encoding on the parameters?

Comment: @KevinO This works.  Thanks for the help.